# Si function on Gibbs phenomenon

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I'm reading Gibbs phenomenon but I'm confused about the statement below.

Since the Dirichlet sum of indicator functions $\chi_{[0,1]}$ is $S_{R} \chi_{[0,1]} (x) = \frac{1}{2}(Si(2R\pi(1-x)) + Si(2R\pi x))$ with $Si(x) = 2/\pi\int_{0}^x \frac{\sin(t)}{t} dt$ then for a decreasing sequence ${x_n}$, we have $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} S_n\chi_{[0,1]} (x_n) \leq \frac{1}{2}(1+Si(\pi)).$

I know the properties of the $Si$ function that $0 \leq Si(x) \leq Si(\pi)$ for all $x>0$ but it can't imply the less equal sign.

Thank you!

Comment: There's some notation confusing me still. What's $S_R$, what's $S_n$?

Comment: Thank you for your concern. $S_n$ is $S_R$ when we replace $R$ by $n$.

Comment: Is the Dirichlet sum of indicator function $\chi_{[0,1]}$ related to the [Dirichlet function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_function) or a [Dirichlet series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series)? Also, for a decreasing sequence $x_n$, is the $n$ in $S_n$ the same as the $n$ in $x_n$, or are you overloading $n$?